# linux Clone and CLONE_PARENT

Tags: linux, c, syscall

Подскажите, почему `clone` не видит `CLONE_PARENT`?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sched.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define STACK_SIZE 10000

char _CHILD_STACK[STACK_SIZE + 1];

int child(void *params)
{
    int c = 0;

    while (1) {
        usleep(50000);
        printf("child turn %d\n", c++);
    }

    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int c = 0;
    int result = clone(child, _CHILD_STACK + STACK_SIZE, CLONE_PARENT, 0);

    printf("result clonde = %d\n", result);

    while (1) {
        usleep(50000);
        printf("parents turn %d\n", c++);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `#define _GNU_SOURCE` добавьте в начало исходного кода.

Comment: не помогло. Также не видит.

Comment: Сообщение об ошибке приложите к вопросу. Также имейте в виду, что я не вносил изменений в ваш код, просто оформил и отформатировал его. В него все еще требуется добавить `#define _GNU_SOURCE` в самое начало, до инклюдов

Comment: заработало! а в чем логика - почему этот #define должен быть до include ?

Comment: Потому, что в заголовочных файлах проверяется наличие этого макроса, и если его нет, специфические для платформы макросы, функции и структуры не будут в них объявлены или будут объявлены иначе. Обычно в [документации](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clone.2.html) к подобным функциям есть указания на использование таких макросов.